# Intuitive understanding and physical significance of Exergy, Gibbs free energy and differences

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics

I have already browsed several questions on this topic and have not found answers to be totally satisfactory.

I am interested in knowing physical significance and an intuitive understanding of [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) & [Exergy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exergy).

From what I have understood so far, Gibbs free energy seems to be a special cae of Exergy (i.e at constant T and P). Is this right? If so, why is Gibbs free energy needed at all? is it not redundant?

what is the significance of having constant T and P in the definition of Gibbs free energy? most practical applications/reactions don't work this way. Most industrial processes/reactions are adiabatic and not isothermal. so how is Gibbs free energy useful there?

In recent times Exergy analysis has been used for understanding  and improving plant efficiencies. If the unit operation in question, which is being investigates, is isothermal can a "Gibbs free energy analysis" be done instead of exergy analysis?

Please start with  a simple intuitive definition of the differences (without getting too mathematical) and then answer the subsequent questions

Comment: Related regarding usefulness of Gibb's Free Energy: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22452/why-is-gibbs-free-energy-more-useful-than-internal-energy

Comment: why is gibbs free energy defined only at constant T and P? when you are fixing T and P in a closed system aren't you fixing V as well?